# Get list of files associated to a commit via API

Tags: api, github, curl, github-api

I'm trying to obtain a list of files modified/deleted/created from a commit by using the GitHub API. So far what I tried is:

```
curl --user "<user>" https://<base_url>/api/v3/repos/<Org>/<repo_name>/commits/refs/heads/<branch_name>
```

However I'm getting back the following message:

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/enterprise/3.3/rest/reference/repos#get-a-commit"
}
```

I'm not sure why. I think this is due to me not understanding what the docs mean by `refs` [here](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.3/rest/commits/commits#get-a-commit), so I'm not sure how to craft that last part properly. What should go here in this last part?

Comment: Though I don't use this API, your ref string looks right to me. What looks wrong is the lack of extra headers for authentication (they are typically required to gain access to anything).

Comment: hey @torek it's odd because I'm following a github tutorial to test it out https://gist.github.com/joyrexus/85bf6b02979d8a7b0308

Comment: That has a section titled **HEADERS** that says "Often when POSTing data you'll need to add headers for things like auth tokens or setting the content type. You can set a header using -H." I assume the earlier parts are describing how to *get* stuff from *open access* repositories.

Comment: I'm starting to arrive at the conclusion that this is tied to an authentication error because I tried a Personal Authentication Token and also my user/password combination and nothing. Ill try to solve it and report back here what I find.